# How to set up a global menu bar for a Maui App

Tags: maui, .net-7.0

I am new to Maui apps and so trying to get my head around a few things.

I have looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/menu-bar  which appears to display a menu bar.

this is what I want - but I want to set this up globally for all pages.  Is there some sort of template system or something in Maui?  I want to initially create a desktop application and I don't want to create a Shell app - I want to create a regular Maui App.  If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Since your app is based on MAUI, you can try to add the `Shell.MenuBarItems` to `AppShell.xaml`.

I tested on the official sample :  [NET MAUI - Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/fundamentals-shell/)

Please refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Xaminals.Controls"
       xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"
       xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Xaminals.Views"
       x:Class="Xaminals.AppShell"
       x:Name="shell"
       FlyoutBackgroundImage="photo.jpg"
       FlyoutBackgroundImageAspect="AspectFill"
       FlyoutHeaderBehavior="CollapseOnScroll"       
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xaminals"
       
       >

  <！-- add   Shell.MenuBarItems here -->

    <Shell.MenuBarItems>
        <MenuBarItem Text="File">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit"  />
        </MenuBarItem>

    </Shell.MenuBarItems>

  <！--  For code brevity, omit some code  -->

    <FlyoutItem Route="animals"
                FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <Tab Title="Domestic"
             Route="domestic"
             Icon="paw.png">
            <ShellContent Route="cats"
                          Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                          Title="Cats"
                          Icon="cat.png"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
            <ShellContent Route="dogs"
                          Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                          Title="Dogs"
                          Icon="dog.png"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
        </Tab>

       
        <ShellContent Route="monkeys"
                      Style="{StaticResource MonkeysShell}"
                      Title="Monkeys"
                      Icon="monkey.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MonkeysPage}" />
        <ShellContent Route="elephants"
                      Style="{StaticResource ElephantsShell}"
                      Title="Elephants"
                      Icon="elephant.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ElephantsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Route="bears"
                      Style="{StaticResource BearsShell}"
                      Title="Bears"
                      Icon="bear.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:BearsPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>

</Shell>
```

Comment: Hi @Martin Thompson, may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.